# what does this mean this.RaisePropertyChanged("")?

Tags: c#, wpf, idataerrorinfo

I have this coded in the implementation section of IDataErrorInfo in a model class for clearing the error once the errors are cleared.

I dont understand which property refresh is being raised here with an empty string?

```
if (raiseNotification)
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("");
```

Comment: All properties changed.

Comment: Looks like they are trying to force all the errors to show for any invalid properties of the IDataErrorInfo interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

In this case, null, String.Empty or "" :^)

Comment: You linked to the wrong page. It actually says "El evento PropertyChanged puede indicar que todas las propiedades del objeto han cambiado utilizando null o String.Empty como el nombre de propiedad en PropertyChangedEventArgs.", which is pretty hard for me to understand. :)

Comment: @hvd  Oh stop it, you `:)`